# QGIS - Merge a polygon line that is splitted

Tags: qgis

Verry much a beginner at this but i have some data that contains trails that are split into smaller sections, id like to be able to merge those small sections into longer trailes based on the close proximity between the parts, how to do this? In total i have about 4000 of those small lines that i need to merge together to make about a total of 100 longer lines/trails.

[image]

Above is an example where i have highlighted an example of this.

I have read something about using buffer at 0 width but that does not seme to work for me, and when i use a higher buffer width im getting buffered with doubble the amount of points.

I have also worked with dissolve but that gives me all of thracks joind together into one big entity, i still want them to be split apart, so in the image id like to end up with 4 different tracks.

[image]

Comment: `Dissolve` could be, what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have played around a bit with that. Thing is that id like to get the different trails as separate entities, dissolve gives me all of the tracks(100+) all joined together. If i use dissolve i then need to split them apart again based on the tracks being distinct from eachother.

Comment: @Erik i have updated the question with other images and some more info.

Comment: You can dissolve by a common ID, as in "all features with this ID become one single feature" - give your tracks such an ID and you're fine.

Comment: There are unfortunatlley no common ID's between the different polygons in a track so i sould need to manually tag all of the 4000 polygons to be able to dissolve by that. This 4000 polygons is just a subset of probably more than 100k so i need a more automated way of doing it.

Comment: Do you care about the data attached to your tracks? If not, run `dissolve`, then `mulit-to-singlepart`.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that but it only lowers the count from 4000 to about 1600. Still way off unfortunatley

Comment: Dissolve as in your 2nd screenshot, than use singlepart to multipart

Answer (score 1):

Dissolve original layer and then execute "Multipart to Single part" tool with dissolved result

Comment: This only partially solves it, this method lowers it from 4000 to abour 1600.